# Problem when use BSP library to audio record on stm32f769i-Discovery

Tags: audio, stm32, recording

I am working with `stm32f769` to record using mems sensor and board support package library for `stm32f769`. But I have problem when using `BSP_AUDIO_IN_Record` function. I realized that the `HAL_DFSDM_FilterRegConvCpltCallback` and `HAL_DFSDM_FilterRegConvHalfCpltCallback` function was not called when execution finished and no sound value was saved, but the application still works fine with the template from ST.

How can I fix this?

My code:

```
int main(void)
{
  /* Enable I-Cache---------------------------------------------------------*/
  
SCB_EnableICache();

  /* Enable D-Cache---------------------------------------------------------*/
  
SCB_EnableDCache();

  /* MCU Configuration--------------------------------------------------------*/

  /* Reset of all peripherals, Initializes the Flash interface and the Systick. */
  HAL_Init();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN Init */

  /* USER CODE END Init */

  /* Configure the system clock */
  SystemClock_Config();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN SysInit */

  /* USER CODE END SysInit */

  /* Initialize all configured peripherals */
  MX_GPIO_Init();
  
/* USER CODE BEGIN 2 */
    
BSP_AUDIO_IN_Init(BSP_AUDIO_FREQUENCY_16K, DEFAULT_AUDIO_IN_BIT_RESOLUTION, DEFAULT_AUDIO_IN_CHANNEL_NBR);
    
BSP_AUDIO_IN_AllocScratch (Scratch_, SCRATCH_BUFF_SIZE);
    
BSP_AUDIO_IN_Record((uint16_t*)&BufferCtl.pcm_buff[0], AUDIO_IN_PCM_BUFFER_SIZE);
    
BufferCtl.fptr = 1;
    
BufferCtl.pcm_ptr = 0;
    
BufferCtl.offset = 0;
    
BufferCtl.wr_state = BUFFER_EMPTY;

  while (1)
  {

  }
}
```

and library:

- stm32f769i_discovery.c
- stm32f769i_discovery.h
- stm32f769i_discovery_audio.c
- stm32f769i_discovery_audio.h
- wm8994.c
- wm8994.h

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you forgot to implement the IRQ functions? They are mandatory in certain use cases (like your own for example), and they have to implement proper `HAL_xxx_IRQHandler()` of a relevant peripheral driver. These IRQ handler functions are processing and calling the right Callback functions.

Look at the file `stm32f7xx_it.c` in STM32 HAL examples. Below you can see code fragment from such file from the `Audio_playback_and_record` STM32 HAL example.

```
/* SAI handler declared in "stm32f769i_eval_audio.c" file */
extern SAI_HandleTypeDef haudio_out_sai;

extern DFSDM_Filter_HandleTypeDef       haudio_in_dfsdm_leftfilter;
extern DFSDM_Filter_HandleTypeDef       haudio_in_dfsdm_rightfilter;

// ...
// ...

/**
  * @brief This function handles DMA2 Stream 4 interrupt request.
  * @param None
  * @retval None
  */
void AUDIO_SAIx_DMAx_IRQHandler(void)
{
  HAL_DMA_IRQHandler(haudio_out_sai.hdmatx);
}

/**
  * @brief This function handles DMA2 Stream 0 interrupt request.
  * @param None
  * @retval None
  */
void AUDIO_DFSDM_DMAx_LEFT_IRQHandler(void)
{
  HAL_DMA_IRQHandler(haudio_in_dfsdm_leftfilter.hdmaReg);
}

/**
  * @brief This function handles DMA2 Stream 0 interrupt request.
  * @param None
  * @retval None
  */
void AUDIO_DFSDM_DMAx_RIGHT_IRQHandler(void)
{
  HAL_DMA_IRQHandler(haudio_in_dfsdm_rightfilter.hdmaReg);
}
```

Another issue could be your method of checking whether audio recording really happened. In the code you provided I cannot find anything like that, so I can't help you without you providing more details.